# Multiple outputs used repeatedly in for loop Julia

Tags: julia

I am using Julia and I've designed a for loop that takes the outputs of a function in one loop and uses them as the input of that function in the next loop (and over and over). When I run this code, Julia flags an "undefined" error, however, if I run the code in debug mode, it executes perfectly. For example, the code looks like this:

```
function do_command(a,b,c,d)
   a = a + 1
   b = split(b, keepempty=false)[1]
   c = split(b, keepempty=false)[1]
   if a == 1000
      d = true
   else
      d = false
   end
   return a, b, c, d
end

for ii in 1:length(x)
   if ii == 1
      a = 0
      b = "string something"
      c = ""
      d = false
   end
   a,b,c,d = do_command(a,b,c,d)
   if d == true
      print(string(b))
      break
   end
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `x` is missing from your example, but I guess this is merely a copy-pasting issue, not your real problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue with your code is that `for` introduces a new scope for each iteration of the loop. That is to say: variable `a` created within the loop body at iteration 1 is not the same as variable `a` created within the loop body at iteration 2.

In order to fix your problem, you should declare variables outside the loop, so that at each iteration, references to them from within the loop body would actually refer to the same variables from the enclosing scope.

I'd go with something like this:

```
function do_command(a,b,c,d)
   a = a + 1
   b = split(b, keepempty=false)[1]
   c = split(b, keepempty=false)[1]
   if a == 1000
      d = true
   else
      d = false
   end
   return a, b, c, d
end

# Let's create a local scope: it's good practice to avoid global variables
let
    # All these variables are declared in the scope introduced by `let`
    a = 0
    b = "string something"
    c = ""
    d = false

    for ii in 1:10 #length(x)
        # now these names refer to the variables declared in the enclosing scope
        a,b,c,d = do_command(a,b,c,d)
        if d == true
            print(string(b))
            break
        end
    end
end
```